# Checkstyle ignore missing resourcebundle properties for variation

Tags: java, wicket, checkstyle, resourcebundle

I have two properties files, e.g. `Foo.properties` and `Foo_demo.properties`. Foo.properties has multiple entries. Foo_demo.propeties overides a subset of these entries.

Foo.properties:

```
text1 = TXT 1
text2 = TXT 2
text3 = TXT 3
```

Foo_demo.properties:

```
text1 = TXT 1 Override
```

Running Checkstyle with the Translation module on this will fail because of two missing translations of entries text2 and text3 in Foo_demo.properties.

Is there a configuration for checkstyle that allows the specified resourcebundle structure?

Background: this is used in a Wicket application, where resourcebundles can be further parametrized with style and variation parameters, see [Wicket i18n](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/i18n.html#i18n_2)

Comment: Just to be sure: Is it your goal to ensure that `Foo_demo.properties` contains only keys which also occur in `Foo.properties`? Or could `_demo` also include keys that are *not* present in `Foo`? In the latter case, you could simply turn off the check.

Comment: The `_demo` (or `_demo_de` etc.) property files will only contain a subset of the original property keys. Right now i do apply a suppress for the Variation files, but would've liked to check them too.

Comment: Gotcha. Then you're out of luck. Checkstyle can't do that at the moment (as of 7.6).